# Deploy wsp without logging to SP server

Tags: 2010, 2013, powershell, solution-package

Can i deploy a wsp using powershell batch file without logging to the sp server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the Remote PowerShell ability. Powershell 2.0 uses the concepts of WIN-RM which involves piping the contents of the remote call and running it on the remote server.

**You need to setup the remote Computer 1st**

- you need to run the following command on your server `Enable-PSRemoting`
- you need to let powershell know that your server machine or remote machine will act as the server. `Enable-WSmanCredSSP -Role Server`

Now Setup the Client Computer:

- edit group policy on your client computer to all credential
  delegation
- run the following command `Enable-PSRemoting`
- enable WSMan CredSSP with the following command `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client –DelegateComputer “NameOfServer”`

Now you can your powershell remotely. check the complete details [over here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2010/06/10/configure-power-shell-for-remote-use-of-sp-2010.aspx)

There is another possible way is with the [SPFarm.Open method, as long as you have access to the database.](http://www.sharepoint.bg/radi/post/Uploading-WSP-files-programmatically-to-remote-SharePoint-farms.aspx)

```
string connString = txtConnectionString.Text;

SPFarm remoteFarm = SPFarm.Open(connString);

remoteFarm.Solutions.Add(txtWSPPath.Text);
```

check this link as well.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Sharepoint-Remote-Deploy-e5603f68